# Pulling one line for a join on one column

Tags: sql

I would like to pull one record for two people that have a matching street but separate values otherwise and all records that do not share an address in the database, patunique being the ID for the table.

For example:

```
Select patunique, last, first, birth, street 
from patient p1, patient p2 
where p2.street = p1.street
```

Data:

```
Patunique,Last,First,Birth,Street
1,Jackson,Fred,01/20/1972,1234 Telegraph Street
2,Jackson,Frank,11/21/1997,1234 Telegraph Street
3,Picasso,Pablo,05/18/1942,5678 Telephone Road
```

Expected Result:

```
Patunique,Last,First,Birth,Street
1,Jackson,Fred,01/20/1972,1234 Telegraph Street
3,Picasso,Pablo,05/18/1942,5678 Telephone Road
```

Even when using a `MAX` on street, it pulls duplicate records as patunique, last, first, and birth are separated.

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: What's the primary key on `patient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Please try this query

```
CREATE TABLE patient (Patunique INT,Last VARCHAR(50),First VARCHAR(50),Birth DATE,Street VARCHAR(50))
DROP TABLE patient
INSERT INTO patient VALUES
(1,'Jackson','Fred','01/20/1972','Telegraph Street')
,(2,'Jackson', 'Frank','11/21/1997', 'Telegraph Street')
,(3,'Picasso','Pablo','05/18/1942','Telephone Road')

Select P1.patunique, P1.last, P1.first, P1.birth, P1.street 
from patient p1
INNER JOIN(
Select P2.street, min(P2.patunique)patunique
from patient p2
group by P2.street
)p2 on p2.patunique = p1.patunique
```